# Strange issue with Jquery Forms, Bootstrap and browser and OS submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, form-submit

I'm working on a page submission form and the issue I'm running into is on MAC OS 10.5 - 10.8 browsers- FF, Chrome, and Safari all work properly, but on Windows 7 using browsers IE 8 +11, and Chrome the submission does not go through, even after saying success.  On FireFox v28 on Windows 7 it is only on some computers that the form is properly submitted and updated.  The site is on Bootstrap.
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-preview-modal-lg" id="preview-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="section-header">
      <h4 id="title-out"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="media media-out"></div>
        <div class="info info-out"></div>
        <div class="body body-out"></div>
        <div class="faq faq-out"></div>
        <div class="external-links external-links-out"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="ajax-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Updating&hellip;</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

and the jquery ajax loading in the footer is

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/v1/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/v1/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/v1/lib/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


    $(document).on({
      ajaxStart: function() {$('#ajax-modal').modal('show');},
      ajaxStop: function() {$('#ajax-modal').modal('hide');}
    });

    $('#publishForm').ajaxForm({
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.success) {$('#success-modal').modal();} else {
          $('#failure-modal').modal();
          console.log(data);
        }
      }
    });
```

Is there something in this that is plugging up on Windows, but not affected by MAC OS?

Answer (score 0):

I would think it is in the `jquery.form.js`-plugin.
What if you just use the jQuery builtin ajax function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#publishForm').submit(function() {
      // prevents the form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        // Showing the #ajax-modal right away rather than wait until the ajax starts.
        $('#ajax-modal').modal('show');
        $.ajax(url, {
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#success-modal').modal();
                } else {
                    $('#failure-modal').modal();
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
            complete: function() {
              // When the ajax-request is complete, it will hide the #ajax-modal (no matter if the request failed or not).
                $('#ajax-modal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: When I use this in the footer, the submission form goes blank. and the "go.." button to select from a dropdown list of pages to edit does not work any longer.  I'm not sure how to proceed..

Comment: I think I've nailed some of it down to a possible conflict in chosen.jquery.js

Comment: If you only use `chosen.jquery.js` to get select(drop down)-lists, you could retrieve it by: `$("#selectElement option:selected").text()` or `$("#selectElement option:selected").val()`